# Install HD7950 and R9 290X on 13.10

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx

I'm Litecoin mining with a R9 290X on Ubuntu 13.10.

Everithing was running fine.

Now i want to attach a HD7950 to the system.

I have uninstalled the properitary drivers, attached the HD7950 and reinstalled the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates-dev
```

Everything runs fine but when I put `sudo aticonfig --lsa` to my console there is only the HD7950 shown:

```
* 0. 02:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series

* - Default adapter
```

It is possible and how to get the two graphic cards with different chip working?

Edit:

`lspci` show two cards with correct naming
Its important to me to use the properitary drivers because if performance

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with no resolution. The R9 290 shows up in `lspci` as:

```
02:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device aac8
```

[Downloading this driver from AMD worked for me.](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx)